# Uncaught TypeError with firefox inspector

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Please help me figure out how to fix this error that shows up in firefox inspector:

> Uncaught TypeError: t is undefined

```
(function(t) {
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["../datepicker"], t) : t(jQuery.datepicker)
})(function(t) {
  return t.regional.fr = {
    closeText: "Fermer",
    prevText: "Précédent",
    nextText: "Suivant",
    currentText: "Aujourd'hui",
    monthNames: ["janvier", "février", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "décembre"],
    monthNamesShort: ["janv.", "févr.", "mars", "avr.", "mai", "juin", "juil.", "août", "sept.", "oct.", "nov.", "déc."],
    dayNames: ["dimanche", "lundi", "mardi", "mercredi", "jeudi", "vendredi", "samedi"],
    dayNamesShort: ["dim.", "lun.", "mar.", "mer.", "jeu.", "ven.", "sam."],
    dayNamesMin: ["D", "L", "M", "M", "J", "V", "S"],
    weekHeader: "Sem.",
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: !1,
    showMonthAfterYear: !1,
    yearSuffix: ""
  }, t.setDefaults(t.regional.fr), t.regional.fr
});
```

Comment: Please note that this most likely has nothing to do with java, but I think you refer to javascript. Also we need to see some actual relevant code in order to help you better.

Comment: Don't post errors/code as images, copy/past it in your question.